# How to change gravity om custom ActionBar in android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I am knew at kotlin and android staff, so need your help. I have created custom ActionBar on a specified activity and wanted to add text to it and a button to open drawerLayout. However, it is not working as I want - text and clickable image are centred and I can't change the gravity.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private var mDrawerToggle: ActionBarDrawerToggle? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)
        supportActionBar?.title = "App name"
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        supportActionBar?.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu)

        mDrawerToggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, binding.drawerMain, binding.toolbar, R.string.days, R.string.abs)
        mDrawerToggle!!.syncState()
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        if (mDrawerToggle?.onOptionsItemSelected(item) == true)
            return true

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bXd9.png)

Setting gravity in xml is not working

[image]

Comment: Looks like you might've set the `<Toolbar>`'s `android:layout_width` to `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent`. Please [edit] your question to add the `activity_main` layout.

Comment: Now It looks the same :D I have edited the topic and added the image

Comment: No, not a screenshot of the results. We need to see the `activity_main.xml` layout file.

Comment: I found problem, but now there is another thing. My activity_main file is drawerLayout and I want to open it with help of button. How can I change button color, because it is white and I don't see where can I chane it? (added screenshot above)